# Specifying complex PropTypes for children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm writing a small `Toolbar` component in React. Here's how it should be used:

```
<Toolbar>
    <ToolbarButtonSearch />
    <ToolbarButtonFold />
</Toolbar>
```

or

```
<Toolbar>
    <ToolbarButtonSearch />
</Toolbar>
```

or

```
<Toolbar>
    <ToolbarButtonFold />
</Toolbar>
```

I'd like to be able to specify that the only children `Toolbar` accepts are one of `ToolbarButtonSearch`, one of `ToolbarButtonFold`, or one of each.

Here's what I have now (not including imports):

```
export default class Toolbar extends React.Component {

    static get propTypes() {
        const acceptedChildren =
            React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
                React.PropTypes.instanceOf(ToolbarButtonFold),
                React.PropTypes.instanceOf(ToolbarButtonSearch)
            ]);

        return {
            children: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
                React.PropTypes.arrayOf(acceptedChildren),
                acceptedChildren
            ]).isRequired
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="toolbar">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm using it:

```
<Toolbar>
    <ToolbarButtonFold />
</Toolbar>
```

This results in the following error:

`Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop 'children' supplied to 'Toolbar'.`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any insight would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's no way to accomplish what you're attempting.  The children property is of type React.PropTypes.node which you could restrict to a single element or an array of elements but the elements themselves aren't instances of the component class.

Comment: That's disappointing and, frankly, surprising. I'd expect React to have this functionality as I'm not attempting anything too far out of the ordinary.

What do you suggest as a better approach to enforcing specific children? _Is_ there an approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to do:

```
customProp: function (props, propName, componentName) {
    props.children.forEach(child => {
        if (!child instanceof ToolbarButtonSearch && !child instanceof ToolbarButtonFold) {
            return new Error(
                'Invalid children supplied to' +
                ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.'
            )
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yes, the issue is that this wouldn't cover the case where `Toolbar` includes both `Fold` _and_ `Search`.

Comment: Then you can wrap the two components inside a `ToolbarChildrenWrapper`, and define it as the propType. Inside this wrapper then you can have, one or both of them.

Comment: So then the `Toolbar` component would look like `Toobar`  > `ToolbarChildrenWrapper` > `[ToolbarFold, ToolbarSearch]`? That would just create the same issue with `ToolbarChildrenWrapper`.

Comment: Understood, maybe you can use something like my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing components (since they have to be imported into Toolbar, anyway), you could just pass props defining if the specific component should be displayed.

```
const Toolbar = ({showButtonSearch = false, showButtonFold = false, buttonSearchProps = {}, buttonFoldProps = {}}) => {

  return (

    <div className='Toolbar'>

      {showButtonSearch ? <ButtonSearch {...buttonSearchProps} /> : null}

      {showButtonFold ? <ButtonFold {...buttonFoldProps} /> : null}

    </div>

  )

}
```

This method would also allow you to pass props for the children as well as any further functionality you need before displaying the children (such as ordering the children a specific way).

Comment: That's an interesting approach. It would get unwieldy with a large number of components, so it's not a perfect solution, but it should work for my use-case. Thanks!